# ¿Cómo transmito información entre dos escenas en JavaFX?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Tenemos un objeto de tipo User que queremos transmitir desde nuestra clase loginController.java para que pueda ser utilizado en nuestra otra clase cartaController.java , y desde esta volver a transmitirlo a modificarPerfilController.java .
El siguiente código es de la clase login:

```
                Parent root = loader.load();
                FXMLCartaController modCarta = (FXMLCartaController)loader.getController();
                modCarta.setUserDesdeCarta(user);
                stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                scene = new Scene(root);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
```

El siguiente codigo es del método initialize de la clase carta:

```
try {
            Navegacion nav = Navegacion.getSingletonNavegacion();
        } catch (NavegacionDAOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLCartaController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        modCarta = this;
```

Este método recibe el user que viene desde loginController hacia cartaController :

```
public void setUserDesdeCarta(User usuari) {
        userLogged = usuari;
    }
```

Y este código es de la clase carta e intenta enviar el user hacia modificarPerfilController:

```
private void modificarPerfil(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLModificarPerfil.fxml"));

        Parent root = loader.load();
        FXMLModificarPerfilController modPerf = (FXMLModificarPerfilController)loader.getController();
        modPerf.setUser(userLogged);
        VBox primaryStage = (VBox) root;
        Scene scene = new Scene(primaryStage);
        bp.setCenter(root);
    }
```

Mi problema es que el objeto user, al ser consultado desde cartaController fuera del método 'setUserDesdeCarta' siempre tiene el valor null, lo cuál no debería ocurrir porque en la clase login y dentro del mismo método 'setUserDesdeCarta' sí muestra valores correctos.

Comment: Puede añadir la clase que extiemde Application?

Answer (score 1):

`FXMLLoader.load("dirección url")`   es un método estático ([documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html)) y retorna null porque no tiene que ver con el objeto instanciado.

en su caso debería ser así

```
private void modificarPerfil(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new  FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLModificarPerfil.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        FXMLModificarPerfilController modPerf = (FXMLModificarPerfilController)loader.getController();
        modPerf.setUser(userLogged);
        VBox primaryStage = (VBox) root;
        Scene scene = new Scene(primaryStage);
        bp.setCenter(root);
    }
```